# Changing the return of true/false with each click though the condition says otherwise in NETLOGO

Tags: netlogo, geocoding

We tried coding to get true/false based on an upper and lower limit. We tried to get "true" if the base moving is 2-5 and everything <2 and >5 should return "False". Instead we are getting true/false with each click when the base moving is changing to fraction. With 1st click we got TRUE for one turtle and base movement that has base movement 3 and that is correct as we set more than 2 should be TRUE. With the next click the base movement changed to 3.5 and we got FALSE that is not correct as we set 2-5 should be TRUE. Here is our code. We couldn't figure out the problem.

```
to setup
 ca
 file-close-all
 resize-world 0 250 0 250
 set-patch-size 2.5
 load-shapefile
 load-map
 get-lor
 get-at
 get-sqr
 create-farmers
 patch-with-sqr
 ask turtles [ set adopted? false ]
 reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ set age age + 1             
    get-probability
    check-moving-prob
    if adopted? = true
    [ let target one-of patches with [ commune? = true ]
      move-to target
    ]
  ]
  tick
  if ticks > 5 [stop]
end

to check-moving-prob
  if base-moving > 5 [ set base-moving 5 ] ; setting boundaries of probability
  if base-moving < 0 [ set base-moving 0 ]
  ifelse base-moving > 2
  [ set adopted? adopted? = true ]
  [ set adopted? adopted? = false ]
  ifelse adopted? = true
  [ set color orange ]
  [ set color black ]
end
```

Comment: In the future, please format your code using the { } icon. You are much more likely to get answers that are helpful if you spend a bit of time making it easy to help you - readable code and a clear statement of the problem is a good starting point

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. We are students and still learning how to code but a project is already due so we didn't know how to arrange the code here to post. Sorry for the inconvenience. I will be more careful from next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have written this (assuming I formatted your code correctly):

```
ifelse base-moving > 2
  [ set adopted? adopted? = true ]
  [ set adopted? adopted? = false ]
```

In NetLogo, the equals sign is a logical test, not an assignment operator. So just like you use `set color orange` to set the colour to orange, you should set the boolean variable to `true` or `false` with:

```
ifelse base-moving > 2
  [ set adopted? true ]
  [ set adopted? false ]
```

What you are doing in your code is checking whether it is true and then assigning the outcome of that test to the variable, as if you had written:

```
let test-result adopted? = true
set adopted? test-result
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved our problem 